# Collection of objects with common Abstract base class

Tags: c#, list, abstract-class, instantiation

I have an abstract class called generic, implemented as follows:

```
public abstract class generic
{
    public string creatorID { get; set; }
    public string itemID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime creationDate { get; set; }
    public string pageName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This is implemented through several classes, such as:

```
public class file : generic
{
    public file(string _itemID, string host, string languageReferenceID)
    {
        DataTable dt = GetRecordsFromDatabase(string _itemID, string host, string languageReferenceID);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            setParameters(dt.Rows[0]);
        ...
    }

    private void setParameters(DataRow dr)
    {
        creatorID = dr["f_MemberID"].ToString();
        itemID = dr["f_ID"].ToString();
        name = dr["f_Name"].ToString();
        creationDate = DateTime.Parse(dr["f_DateCreated"].ToString());
        pageName = "files";
        ...
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create a List of objects of different instantiations of that abstract generic class. Here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
    public List<generic> getAlerts(string host, string languageReferenceID)
    {            
        DataTable dt = GetAlertsFromDatabase(host, languageReferenceID);

        List<generic> alertList = new List<generic>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            generic g = new generic();

            g.itemID = dr["itemID"];
            g.description = dr["description"];
            g.pageName = dr["pageName"];

            g.Add(m);
        }

        return alertList;
    }
```

Now, of course, this is throwing an error on the line with:

`generic g = new generic();`

Since generic is an abstract class, it can't be instantiated as an object.

My question is - how do I accomplish my objective, given the requirements I've listed? Should I create a new class implementing the abstract class generic, for the sole purpose of instantiating lists of type generic? That seems like an odd solution to me, but it's the only thing I can think of right now.

Comment: `What I'm trying to do is create a List of objects of different instantiations of that abstract generic class` No, that's not what your code is doing.  If you make your code and your requirements match, you won't have a problem.

Comment: You don't want an instance of `generic`. You want an instance of some subclass of `generic`. If `getAlerts()` could be populating that `List<generic>` with more than one different subclass, maybe `getAlerts()` should use a class factory which looks at a `DataRow` and decides what *subclass* of `generic` should be created, and creates it.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear - there are many classes implementing the abstract class generic. File is just one of them. My database call will return a series of rows that correspond to different types of objects, all of which implement generic. I want a list that contains all of those objects, and the list should be of type generic.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, just realised that is exactly what I should be doing. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @KiranRamaswamy: You need to figure out what type of objects you want in the list.  Once you figure that out, and make your classes match that, you won't have a problem.

Comment: See @SLaks comment - that is not what you said in the question and not what your comment says. If you want a list to contain "all of those [different types of] objects", then you need to create those different types of objects and add them to the generic list.

Comment: You didn´t provide anything about how you determine the actual type of the object that should be created from a given row. So we can only guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, this looks like [a class factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

You need a method that takes a `DataRow`, looks at its fields, and decides which subclass of `generic` should be created for that row. Then it creates the appropriate object `newObj`, calls `newObj.setParameters(dr)`, and returns `newObj`.

Preferably, the actual factory method doesn't take a `DataRow`, but rather just the one scalar value (int, string, whatever) that indicates the type to be created.

Perhaps the class factory is passed in by dependency injection; you could go simple or elaborate on this.

Comment: Thanks for the super-fast responses everyone. I've marked Ed's response as the answer since it's the one I got the idea from. For reference, how I solved it was to use the Activator.CreateInstance method to create an instance of the specific class that instantiates generic, and then type-cast that back down to generic. Might not be the cleanest solution, but it does work for my purposes!